# mouseup event alpine js

Tags: onclick, mouseup, alpine.js

Is there any mouseup event in alpinejs?
@click.away is not suitable, because you actually need to click somewhere else.
And in my case one event should be triggered when button is pressed and another when mousekey is released no matter where courser is.

Update:
Right now I have this code:

```
        <div x-data="{ buttonPresed: false }">
            <button 
            @click=" buttonPresed = true " 
            class="h-10 w-40 border rounded-lg bg-white text-black font-bold">Some Button</button>
            <div x-show=" buttonPresed === true " class="text-lg text-white font-bold">Button pressed</div>
        </div>
```

Text "Button pressed" is shown after the button is pressed.
I need it to be hided (buttonPresed=false) when mouse button is released.
So text is only shown when user's finger on the mouse button.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any DOM events with Alpine.js's `x-on:[event-name]` or `@[event-name]` in this case `x-on:mouseup="console.log($event)"` or `@mouseup="console.log($event)"` will log the mouseup event when it's triggered.

Comment: Could you please look at question update? Because I kinda did not understand how to use the functionality you mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah what you've done is fine, if you had the code in the initial question I would have come up with something similar.

Comment: Many thanks anyway. Your answer gave me the idea)) Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Even though @Hugo partly answered my question I decided to write a complete answer.

```
        <div x-data="{ buttonPresed: false }">
            <button
            x-on:mouseup="buttonPresed=false" 
            x-on:mousedown="buttonPresed = true"
            {{-- don't use!!!!!: @click=" buttonPresed = true "  --}}
            class="h-10 w-40 border rounded-lg bg-white text-black font-bold">Some Button</button>
            <div x-show=" buttonPresed === true " class="text-lg text-white font-bold">Button pressed</div>
        </div>
```

The commented part is very important, because the functionality works how it should work only if both events triggered with "x-on".